# How many gradle files can inherit from one another? How "deep" can subprojects be?

Tags: gradle

I have a project with the following structure:

```
Root project 'ExampleProject'
+--- Project ':client'
|    +--- Project ':client:android'
|    +--- Project ':client:core'
|    +--- Project ':client:desktop'
|    +--- Project ':client:html'
|    \--- Project ':client:ios'
+--- Project ':common'
+--- Project ':editor'
\--- Project ':server'
```

There is one settings.gradle like so:

```
include ":client", ":common", ":editor", ":server",
        "client:desktop", ':client:android', ':client:ios', 
        ':client:html', ':client:core'
rootProject.name = "ExampleProject"
```

There are build.gradle files at every level.  There is one at the project root, one at the client root, one at client:android root, etc.

It appears that the client:android is not inheriting plugins,etc from the build.gradle for the :client project.  Is there a maximum (of 2?) of how many build.gradle files can be "chained" and inherited from?

The client build.gradle has a block like this that is not being inherited:

```
project(":client:android") {  //plugins and dependencies here 
                                                                 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special parent-child relationship in gradle other than the root project and all other modules. Meaning there is no core concept of a subproject that is also a "parent" to it's own subprojects. The documentation seems a little misleading in that respect. It says: "Properties and methods declared in a project are inherited to all its subprojects." But I think this really only relates to the root build.gradle and all others, it is not recursive. Maybe that already answers your question.

#### Why inheritance is not desired

It is also generally undesirable to have any such concept, because gradle tries to be as fast as possible by being modular and incremental. So `build.gradle` files should be self-sufficient without needing any parent to run (other than the root build.gradle). This is a fundamental difference to Maven, which relies heavily on inheritance to avoid duplicating XML code.

So while you could write custom gradle code to achieve this kind of inheritance, you probably should not. Instead to share gradle code, you should prefer composition (`apply from`), add custom code/custom plugins in the `buildSrc` folder, or define submodule groups in the root `build.gradle` file.

#### Workaround for this kind of project setup

So what several gradle projects would do is to define all subproject groups and their configuration in the root `build.gradle` file like so:

```
def clientProjects() {
    return subprojects.findAll {
            // some predicate that is true only for client projects
    }
}

configure(clientProjects()) {
    apply plugin: ...
}
```